# How does "Open on mouse over" works?

Tags: modeling, customization, mouse

What will be happens when "Open on mouse over" in preferences is active? How does it work can you give me an example please, Thanx

Answer (score 1):

*'Open on mouse over'* is for menus.

This option allow to open a menu, just because the mouse cursor is over it.

If the option is not checked, you need to click on menus to open them.

Most of things are documented in Blender. If you keep the mouse cursor above the option, you'll have some explanation

[image]:

Comment: Thanks for answer but can you please tell me the  concrete example  of how does it works? I understand in theory how does it works but I can't reproduce it on practice... can you give me the screenshot in which menu it can be use?

Comment: @Piton812, this is just a way to activate menus. Just try it yourself, that will be the simplest way.